# Capturing Session ID from URL in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to capture a session ID from a URL so that the ID will follow a user throughout the site and then get captured when they fill in a form.

The URL will look something like this.

http://www.mysite.co.za/?campaign=the_campaign_name

Then I inserted this code into the top of my Joomla template file:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['campaign']=$_GET['campaign'];
```

Will this capture the session (the_campaign_name) and will this work with Joomla as I know Joomla uses its own session ID's?

When I check the sessions I just get a PHPSESSID showing its session.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it should work, joomla is PHP. and what you are trying to do is PHP, if you want to check all the created session variable then try

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

**Update:**

it seems joomla stores the session variables in database, according to the documentation you need to set and access session variable in joomla like this.

to set session variable

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('campaign', $_GET['campaign']);
```

to get session variable

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->get('campaign');
```

it seems joomla upon initialization destroys the regular session variable for some security reason they say, here is the link from joomla documentation to help you http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_access_session_variables_set_by_an_external_script

hope this helps. and always remember to sanitize user input with proper validation. before using it.

Comment: All I get is
    array(0) { }
when I try that.

Comment: So my code is not capturing the session from the URL? Or just not storing it?

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, thank you very much for your help!
I am just not sure how to implement the doc on accessing variables set by an external script.

JPATH_BASE needs to reflect my directory structure?

Comment: i am sorry i am not a joomla developer, moreover that was just for reference, i guess you just need this three line of code to set and get session variable  `$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('campaign', $_GET['campaign']); $session->get('campaign');`

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I do have the three lines but it doesn't seem to get the variable. I shall see if I can work something out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have worked for me, if this helps anyone:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['campaign'])) {
        $campaign = $_GET['campaign'];
    }

    setcookie('CampaignName', $campaign);
?>
```

Not sure if it's even the correct way but it worked for me on Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Joomla, why not make use of the Joomla framework?

To set:

```
JFactory::getSession()->set('campaign', JRequest::getVar('campaign'), $optional_namespace);
```

To get:

```
JFactory::getSession()->get('campaign', $optional_default_value, $optional_namespace);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have given that a try no luck there either. 
I am wondering if there is something in this site that is preventing the sessions from being captured.

Comment: Are your users logging in our logging out at any point? When either of these actions happens, a new session is generated so you might be losing session data that way. Is that possible? You may also want to check your session settings in the Joomla admin. What's the lifetime set to? Are you using the DB for session storage?